# mysql query with inner join returns duplicate entry

Tags: php, mysql

I tried this code in phpmysql

```
 SELECT p.ID, p.post_title, p.post_name
 FROM `wp6p_popularpostsdata` AS pps
     INNER JOIN `wp6p_posts` AS p ON pps.`postid`= p.`ID`
 WHERE p.post_type = "post"
     AND pps.last_viewed > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
 ORDER BY pps.`pageviews` DESC 
 LIMIT 4
```

and it gives the results properly

```
1336Reading Between The Lines. reading-between-the-lines
824 Benefits of Watching Anime benefits-of-watching-anime
1427 The Day Goes By. life-goes-by
1950 Click here if you want to be rich want-to-be-rich
```

But when I use it in my php file, it returns

READING BETWEEN THE LINES. READING BETWEEN THE LINES. THE DAY GOES BY. BENEFITS OF WATCHING ANIME

```
global $wpdb;
$interval = "1 WEEK";
$now = current_time('mysql');
$top4 = $wpdb->get_results(
'SELECT p.ID, p.post_title, p.post_name
 FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'popularpostssummary` AS pps
     INNER JOIN `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts` AS p ON pps.`postid`= p.`ID`
 WHERE p.post_type = "post"
     AND pps.last_viewed > DATE_SUB("' . $now . '", INTERVAL ' . $interval . ')
 ORDER BY pps.`pageviews` DESC 
 LIMIT 4;', ARRAY_A
);
foreach( $top4 AS $index => $row ) {
$class = ( $index == ( count( $top4 ) - 1 ) ) ? ' last' : '';
$url = get_permalink( $row['ID'] );
echo '<li class="trendingPost'.$class.'">' . 
     '<a href="' . $url . '">'.$row['post_title'].'</a></li>';
}
```

How can I prevent the duplicate result?

Comment: Don't forget to include 'post_status="published"' in your query.  Also check your popularposts table for multiple records with the same id

Comment: Thank you, can I use two AND's for that?
like WHERE p.post_type = "post" 
AND p.post_status="published"
     AND pps.last_viewed > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)

Comment: Yes, you can combine conditions; I guess the first limit you'd hit is [max_allowed_packet](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/packet-too-large.html) ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is tempting to use `exists` rather than a `join`:

```
SELECT p.ID, p.post_title, p.post_name
FROM wp6p_posts p 
WHERE p.post_type = 'post' AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM wp6p_popularpostsdata pps
              WHERE pps.postid = p.ID AND
                    pps.last_viewed > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
             );
```

However, this doesn't allow you to order by `pageviews`.  Instead, use aggregation:

```
SELECT p.ID, p.post_title, p.post_name
FROM wp6p_popularpostsdata pps INNER JOIN 
     wp6p_posts p
     ON pps.postid = p.`ID`
WHERE p.post_type = 'post' AND
      pps.last_viewed > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
GROUP BY p.ID, p.post_title, p.post_name
ORDER BY MAX(pps.pageviews) DESC 
LIMIT 4;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I already found that the cause was I was using popularpostssummary in my query instead of popularpostsdata

Comment: Hm, this really intrigues me. What is substantially better about using the GROUP BY/MAX approach here, given that the JOIN is on a 1:1 relation of a subset of wp6p_posts? (I assume there is a benefit, since Gordon is way better in sql than me, so this is a "real question"™ ;-))

Comment: @VolkerK . . . If the join were really 1-1, then the OP would not be getting duplicates.

Comment: I think it's 1:1 with the popularpostsdata and not in popularpostssummary, since I get duplicates only in popularpostssumarry

Comment: I just tried this in phpmysql, popularpostssummary, it returns duplicate using my old code, and this one fixes it. Thanks again :D

Comment: Yeah, I think it's 1:1, given the context. I believe wp6p_popularpostsdata to be an "extension" to the wp6p_posts table, some fields that _could_ in principle be in the wp6p_posts table that have been "outsourced" since it's a wordpress plugin that doesn't want to (and shouldn't) alter the original table definition.